# Back Navigation after a Notification

Tags: android

I have an app that contains a Notification.  I want to set the "back" navigation behavior after the Notification is selected.  I have two Activities: MainActivity and GoogleFormActivity.  The Notification starts the GoogleFormActivity and I want the back button to go back to MainActivity.  I tried [this](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html) to no avail.  Here's my code:

Manifest.xml:

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.ican.activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.ican.activities.GoogleFormActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_google_form"
        android:parentActivityName="com.ican.activities.MainActivity" >
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.ican.activities.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

Here's the code when my Notification is selected:

```
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, GoogleFormActivity.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this).
            addParentStack(GoogleFormActivity.class).
            addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
    int mId = 1;
    mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```

As far as I can tell, this looks exactly like the Android docs.  But when I press back after GoogleFormActivity starts, the app navigates out of the app to the home screen.  I don't understand what's going on.  Any ideas?

**Edit** I must apologize folks.  This same code that didn't work yesterday now works today.  I swear something is up with Android Studio.  This is the second or third time this sort of thing has happened.

Answer (score 0):

When you tap on `back button` it will close current activity. it means it will not open any activities. just closing the current activity.. The activities are arranged in a `stack (the back stack)`, in the order in which each activity is opened. If the user presses the `Back button`, the current activity is popped from the stack and destroyed. The previous activity in the stack is resumed, if the stack contains that activity. When an activity is destroyed, the system does not retain the activity's state. So, when you are coming from notifications you will open only one activity. it will not goes back to main activity, bez it was not opened. you have to use `Intent` to navigate to particular activity.  [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you're saying.  The "Preserving Navigation when Starting an Activity" article says that I should be able to go back to the MainActivity.

Comment: The activities are arranged in a `stack (the back stack)`, in the order in which each activity is opened. If the user presses the `Back button`, the current activity is popped from the stack and destroyed. The previous activity in the stack is resumed, if the stack contains that activity..... please read this still did't understand let me know.

Comment: I understand what you're saying.  But when I look at the "Preserving Navigation when Starting an Activity", I see: "Notifications from the Gmail app demonstrate this. When you click a notification for a single email message, you see the message itself. Touching Back takes you backwards through Gmail to the Home screen, just as if you had entered Gmail from the Home screen rather than entering it from a notification."  And it seems like I should be able to accomplish what I am trying to.

Comment: By using the intent you can navigate to Home activity like this Intent intent=new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

Comment: This isn't about overriding the back button and starting an activity, this is about having a very specific, well-defined backstack of tasks when you land on a screen that you didn't access via the normal app operation so that everything looks like they did to the user. I.e., when you click a gmail notification and go to that particular email, clicking back does NOT take you to home, it should take you to the list of your emails - if you have no underlying backstack, the only task to be popped will be the current one, and the user will incorrectly see the home screen

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onBackPressed();
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
```

**Add this in your GoogleFormActivity**

Answer (score 0):

try to do this,

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main, newFragment).addToBackStack("fragBack").commit();
```